Getting Specific value a multi-nested JSON file
I've tried everything I can think of to extract a known value from a JSON response. I know that there have been similar questions and I've tried their answers but they haven't returned the values I've been trying to get.
I've run $results = json_decode($response, true); and then tried to use a loop to read the JSON to find a Key Value pair but it doesn't seem to work. All I want is the part of the file that says "DELIVERED". I've stared at this until I'm cross-eyed and can't come up with a simple way to extract the information. Any help is greatly appreciated.
array(1) {
  ["trackResponse"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["shipment"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["inquiryNumber"]=>
        string(18) "MyID_Number"
        ["package"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(12) {
            ["trackingNumber"]=>
            string(18) "MyID_Number"
            ["deliveryDate"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["type"]=>
                string(3) "DEL"
                ["date"]=>
                string(8) "20240403"
              }
            }
            ["deliveryTime"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["type"]=>
              string(3) "DEL"
              ["endTime"]=>
              string(6) "162314"
            }
            ["activity"]=>
            array(8) {
              [0]=>
              array(7) {
                ["location"]=>
                array(2) {
                  ["address"]=>
                  array(4) {
                    ["city"]=>
                    string(7) "BRAXTON"
                    ["stateProvince"]=>
                    string(2) "MS"
                    ["countryCode"]=>
                    string(2) "US"
                    ["country"]=>
                    string(2) "US"
                  }
                  ["slic"]=>
                  string(4) "3921"
                }
                ["status"]=>
                array(4) {
                  ["type"]=>
                  string(1) "D"
                  ["description"]=>
                  string(10) "DELIVERED "
                  ["code"]=>
                  string(2) "FS"
                  ["statusCode"]=>
                  string(3) "011"
                }
                ["date"]=>
                string(8) "20240403"
                ["time"]=>
                string(6) "162314"
                ["gmtDate"]=>
                string(8) "20240403"
                ["gmtOffset"]=>
                string(6) "-05:00"
                ["gmtTime"]=>
                string(8) "21:23:14"
              }
              [1]=>
              array(7) {
                ["location"]=>
                array(2) {
                  ["address"]=>
                  array(4) {
                    ["city"]=>
                    string(7) "Jackson"
                    ["stateProvince"]=>
                    string(2) "MS"
                    ["countryCode"]=>
                    string(2) "US"
                    ["country"]=>
                    string(2) "US"
                  }
                  ["slic"]=>
                  string(4) "3921"
                }
                ["status"]=>
                array(4) {
                  ["type"]=>
                  string(1) "I"
                  ["description"]=>
                  string(22) "Out For Delivery Today"
                  ["code"]=>
                  string(2) "OT"
                  ["statusCode"]=>
                  string(3) "021"
                }
                ["date"]=>
                string(8) "20240403"
                ["time"]=>
                string(6) "091057"
                ["gmtDate"]=>
                string(8) "20240403"
                ["gmtOffset"]=>
                string(6) "-05:00"
                ["gmtTime"]=>
                string(8) "14:10:57"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


start from accessing $results['trackResponse']. output this array. then access $results['trackResponse']['shipment']. Then $results['trackResponse']['shipment'][0]. And so on. You see, it's not about JSOn at all. It's all about basic array access.

"doesn't seem to work" isn't a fixable problem, especially in relation to code nobody can see! But the duplicate question explains the principles of decoding the JSON, and then learning how to access the elements in the resulting array (including nested arrays). Once you understand the principles you can (sometimes with a bit of trial and error) access anything you want in any such data structure. If you're still feeling your way, go one level down at a time, then output the next bit of the structure using var_dump or print_r so you can see what to target next, and gradually build up

God but I'm stupid sometimes. I over thought this and should have gone for the simple path @YourCommonSense suggested.  I guess I need more coffee and more sleep. I was trying a foreach loop to parse through everything and that is what wasn't working. Just going through each output was easier and more direct. Thanks for the clue-by-4 upside my head.
